# Foreground and Background

Tags: process, kill, background-process, jobs

I just wanted to make sure that I understand the foreground and background process. Let's say, I have a program Hello_world.

If I want to start the program I type in the foreground:

```
Hello_world
```

Then if I want to continue Hello_world in the background I type:

```
bg Hello_world
```

If I want to kill the job I type:

```
kill -9 %(job#)
```

Also, how would I check to see if the job is terminated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you type:

```
jobs
```

It should tell you what status are your background jobs in.

See [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/jobs.1p.html) for further info.

**Example:**

```
./job &
```

Now it is running on background.

You can kill it by:

```
kill %1
```

or use any switch like:

```
-HUP

-TERM

-KILL
```

In any case in the end you would like to see:

```
[1]+  Terminated              ./job
```

And this is done again by `jobs` command.

Answer (score 0):

Great [explanation by @Vlastimil](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/351525/80216#351527).
I would add only that you can jump between foreground / background:

```
fg %background_job_ID
```

e.g.,

```
fg %2
```

and now you brought it to foreground, you are in that context, meaning that you can:

pause (stop/suspend): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

interrupt:      <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>   (this will typically
cause the process to terminate; i.e., exit)

During all of this you can see what is running, what is paused and what is terminated by executing the `jobs` command.

But yeah, that is kind of the main aspects of background / foreground via shell management.